# How does a program unfreeze?

Tags: windows, freeze

More often than not, one of my programs stops running and it becomes unresponsive. One of the more notorious examples would be the windows task manager:

[image]

When a program freezes like this, it usually just hangs like that and I kill the application. However, in some cases the application **unfreezes** and resumes as if nothing had happened.

How does this work?

I would assume that when a program is stuck like this, it can't do anything but die, otherwise it wouldn't be stuck in the first place. Answers to this question are *perhaps* dependent on the language the application was written in, in that case feel free to use Java or C as a reference.

Comment: This question is too vague, and not appropriate for this site at the same time. Howeever, severak causes can be behind this. One I frequently encounter is IO contention. If the IO load is too high, the apps usually can't continue it's work until its operations are done. (e.g. several applications are transferring data to and from disk). When the load is gone, the app continues its work.

Comment: This also happens, when Windows has problems working on queued messages from the window-message-loop. As a result, the UI may become unresponsive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the program is running something that takes a long time
(e.g. doing heavy calculations, waiting for a web reply)
on the UI thread itself, than the UI thread is stuck and can no longer 
perform message pumping: 
[UI Thread both running message pump AND executing code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963327/ui-thread-both-running-message-pump-and-executing-code)

When this happens the "not responsive" message may appear. 
If the long term task is completed , than the program  "unfreezes".

Comment: Indeed, the UI thread is the key thing here: an application that is stuck because of IO contention or similar will only be "not responding" if it's the UI thread that's doing the IO.  If it's a background thread, the app should stay responsive.